# Shortcut to exit equation in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, equations

Is there a shortcut to come out of an in-line equation whilst also allowing it to execute the shortcuts in the function. As I understand it, this is only possible by pressing enter - but this is inconvenient as it pushes you to a new line.

A similar question has been asked already however the solutions proposed there (press right) simply leave the equation box without it being converted into equation formatting so it isn’t really a solution. On Notion, for example, you press enter within an equation and it moves you to the character just after an equation, without moving you to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

This key-combination works for me and should work for you:

> <kbd>Right-arrow</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>